# How do I prevent ListView footer from becoming selected?

Tags: android, listview, focus, selection

I have a ListView which can be navigated with the dpad.  It has a footer.  I want to prevent navigation into the footer with the dpad.  I have set focusable and focusableInTouchMode of the footer view itself to false; this makes no difference (so I deduce that it is not actually *focus* I am seeing, but rather *selection*).

How do I prevent the footer from becoming selected?

Comment: did u tried this footerView.setClickable(false);

Comment: @Tilsan: I believe so, but I'll try it again; thanks.  Will report back with results.

Comment: @Tilsan: I wound up not even trying that (believe I already did); see the approved answer below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You might try using this when adding the footer view:

```
listView.addFooterView(view, data, false);//third argument indicates footer is unselectable
```

Haven't done this myself, so just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the fix.  I had been using the single-argument version of addFooterView.

Comment: Thank you. Spent hours making workarounds, and it was this simple. :'(